# iOS 6 and Mapkit : User location

Tags: iphone, location, mapkit, ios6

I was suprise when i saw that my app can't know where I am located with a MapKit on iOS6 !

I just want to zoom to user's location when the map is starting ! How can I do it ?

Please help me

Thank you so much !! 
(PS: I saw that the CLCoordinate for sending a request for routing is working fine)

Comment: Do you mean your app works without any changes in iOS 5 or earlier?  Please show your code.  What debugging have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that showsUserLocation doesn't have any effect? Or does your location monitoring isn't updating you position? I tested both in iOS 6, works for me. Maybe you could post some code.

EDIT:

Seems like location monitoring is not activated in your app.
First of all you have to do sth like this to enable the cllocation manager:

```
if (nil == locationManager)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

//set the delegate for the location manager
locationManager.delegate = self;
// set your desired accuracy
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

At that point the blue location indicator should be visible. As long as you've set showsUserLocation = YES on your map.